# Share configuration between Spring cloud config clients

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm trying to share configuration between *Spring Cloud* clients with a *Spring Cloud* config server which have a file-based repository:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}

// application.yml
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  profiles:
    active: native

test:
  foo: world
```

One of my *Spring Cloud* client use the `test.foo` configuration, defined in the config server, and it is configured like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class HelloWorldServiceApplication {

    @Value("${test.foo}")
    private String foo;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello " + this.foo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}

// boostrap.yml
spring:
  cloud:
      config:
        uri: ${SPRING_CONFIG_URI:http://localhost:8888}
      fail-fast: true

// application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: hello-world-service
```

Despite this configuration, the `Environment` in the *Spring Cloud* Client doesn't contains the `test.foo` entry (cf `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'test.foo'`)

However it's works perfectly if i put the properties in a `hello-world-service.yml` file, in my config server file-based repository.

> Maven dependencies on *Spring Cloud* Brixton.M5 and *Spring Boot* 1.3.3.RELEASE with `spring-cloud-starter-config` and `spring-cloud-config-server`

Comment: @AliDehghani The question have been updated with the correct spelling

Comment: You said "file-base repository" but you didn't show the configuration for it, nor did you say what the location of the `application.yml` is.

Comment: @DaveSyer i'm saying `file-base repository` because i'm using the [`native` spring profile](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_file_system_backend). The `application.yml` file is in the local classpath like standard spring boot application

Comment: If I remember correctly we don't server the config server's own application.yml by default, otherwise ever service would try and run with `server.port: 8888`. Put `test.foo` in `application.yml` in the same dir where you put `hello-world-service.yml`.

Comment: @spencergibb `hello-world-service.yml` file is in the same dir than the `application.yml`. I finally found the cause of my issue (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Spring Cloud documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_sharing_configiration_with_all_applications)

> With the "native" profile (local file system backend) it is
>   recommended that you use an explicit search location that isn’t part
>   of the server’s own configuration. Otherwise the application*
>   resources in the default search locations are removed because they are
>   part of the server.

So i should put the shared configuration in an external directory and add the path in the `application.yml` file of the `config-server`.

```
// application.yml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: file:/Users/herau/config-repo

// /Users/herau/config-repo/application.yml
test:
  foo: world
```